# LightBox dose image will not load

Tags: html, css, lightbox, lightbox2

Hi there i have played around with lightbox now for a long time but there is one problem. I got an image size of 1.80mb and 1608 x 1080. Now this image will not load what so ever. My question is , is it because its to big in file size and i need to compress it to something like 30.2 kb or am i doing something wrong in lightbox? Just to be clear this is when you click on the thumbnail, it just keeps on loading.

My html:

```
<div class = "lightbox">
    <a href="images/image4.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image4t.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/image5.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image5t.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/image6.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image6t.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/image7.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image7t.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/image8.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image8t.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/image9.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image9t.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

If you need anything else please feel free to ask. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: Do you get any javascript or network error ? Are you sure the image isn't loading, isn't it just slow so you have to wait a bit longer to see it ?

Comment: Can you show us an online demo?

Comment: Have you started the script? [Lightbox: How to use](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/#how-to-use)

Comment: @tiagojpdias yes and not it just dose not load i left it for like 5 mins artdude. And i will try billy

Comment: can you set up a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Not really sure how to i used this site to get everthing from: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/